# Is aiohttp read different from requests.iter_content?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am changing the requests version to aiohttp version.

#### requests

```py
with requests.get(url='url', headers=headers, stream=True) as r:
    with open('request_test.mp4', 'wb') as f:
        print(int(r.headers['Content-Length']) // (1024 * 10)) # output: 9061.
        for index, chunk in enumerate(r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024 * 10)):
            print(index) # output: 1 2 3 .... 9061.
            f.write(chunk)
```

#### aiohttp

```py
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    async with session.get(url='url', headers=headers, timeout=_timeout) as res:
        print(res.content_length // (1024 * 10)) # output: 9061.
        with open('aiotest.mp4', 'wb') as fd:
            count = 0
            while True:
                chunk = await res.content.read(1024 * 10)
                print(count) # output: 1 2 3 .... 11183
                count += 1
                if not chunk:
                    break
                fd.write(chunk)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res.content.read(1024 * 10)` reads *up to* 10 KiB per call, not exactly 10 KiB.

The sum of all chunk lengths should be exactly the same as returned by `res.content_length`.